# mass redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I try to use .htaccess to redirect all url like:

```
http://example.com/?view-RANDOMNUMBER (ex. http://example.com/?view-1505)
```

to a page like:

```
http://example.com/test-page.php
```

Please, could you help me?

Thanks

br0k3n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view-\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ test-page.php? [R,L]
```

If you need to use `view-RANDOMNUMBER` in `test-page.php` use instead

```
RewriteRule ^$ test-page.php [R,L]
```

Without final `?`.
If you want the link does not change in the browser, use `[L]` instead `[R,L]`

Comment: Thanks :) If I want to pass a 404 error for the page indexed into the serp? Currently I find some urls into the serp and I want to remove them redirecting the users to a default page, but at the same time I'd like to give a 404 error, so in the futere weeks Google will remove them from the serp. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can try with [R=404]. But I think you must send the 404 header from your page `test-page.php`. In this case use just `RewriteRule ^$ test-page.php [L]`